Maximum size of network following certain properties
Let's say that there is a network with $n$ nodes, each with a degree of at most $d$. Given that it is possible to travel from any node to any other through a path of length at most $l$, what is the maximum value of $n$ in terms of $d$ and $l$?
I was able to come up with an upper bound for $n$:
$\begin{align*} n \leq \left\{\begin {aligned} & 1+d\cdot\frac{(d-1)^l-1}{d-2} \quad & d \neq 2 \\ & 1+2l \quad & d = 2       \end{aligned} \right. \end{align*} $
I did this by starting with a tree-like structure spreading out from a central node, maintaining a degree of $d$ at all nodes except the terminal leaf nodes at the end. I then tried adding edges between the terminal leaf nodes, till the property mentioned above was satisfied.
It is clear that there cannot be more nodes than the limit given above; but I have not been able to prove that this
is the best upper bound.
The formula definitely gives the best upper bound for small values of $d$ and $l$. In particular, it was easy to verify for the following cases:

$d=1$
$d=2$
$l=1$
$d=3, l=2$

But I'm not sure if the formula generalizes. I'm not too well-versed with graph theory, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_graph

@CalvinLin yeah, sorry, I meant to say 1+2l, not 1+2d. Stupid typo.

This is the (very well studied) Degree-Diameter Problem. We usually use $\Delta$ for the maximum degree, and $d$ for the diameter.
You can find a survey on this problem here:
https://www.combinatorics.org/ds14
The bound you have given is known as the Moore Bound.
The short version is: you are correct to be skeptical of this bound. It does hold for a few graphs: The Petersen graph with $\Delta = 3$, $d=2$, the Hoffman-Singleton graph with $\Delta = 7$ and $d=2$, and possibly a graph (unknown, open problem) graph with $\Delta = 57$, $d=2$.
A "bipartite" version of the bound holds for a few infinite families of graphs, but is again not generally best possible.
Finding better bounds is exceedingly hard, and the subject of much research (as you can see in the survey above).

Thanks so much for this - it is exactly what I was looking for
